# Unable to extract an attribute using the Selenium package

Tags: python, selenium, attributes

The general idea is to extract DOM using Selenium packages.

Specifically, the objective is to extract the value of **`max`** which reside in the class `pagination__input hide-phone` as shown below

```
<div class="pagination__input hide-phone">
   <input type="number" name="page" max="12" value="1">
</div>
```

The website is accessible from this [link](https://www.freepik.com/search?dates=any&format=search&page=1&query=Polygonal%20Human&sort=popular).

To achieve this, the following code were drafted.

```
maxPage = self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector( "[class='pagination__input hide-phone']" )
valueMax=maxPage.get_attribute( 'max' )
```

However, the following error was thrown.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

May I know what is the problem.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit 2**

As suggested by @Kunduk.

As per @Kunduk, the following line has been tailor accordingly. Specifically, add the `self.`

```
print( WebDriverWait( self.browser, 10 ).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.pagination__input.hide-phone>input[name='page']") ) ).get_attribute( "max" ) )
```

However, I got the following error

[image]

**Edit 1:**

As suggested by @Josh

```
pages = self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector( "[class='pagination__input hide-phone']" )
maxPages = [page for page in pages if page.get_attribute('max')]
```

However, it return the result of `[]`,also as shown by the figure below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this selector `div.pagination__input > input` and induce [`WebDriverWait()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) :

```
driver.get('https://www.freepik.com/search?dates=any&format=search&page=1&query=Polygonal%20Human&sort=popular')
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.pagination__input > input')))
print(element.get_attribute('max'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I had to accept @kunduk answer

Comment: Follow up to your response? How to know whether to include the div (right after the .pagination_input)?

Comment: @balandongiv `div.pagination__input` is unique, that is enough to identify

Answer (score 1):

To get the max value of the page induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `presence_of_element_located`() and following `css selector`.

```
driver.get("https://www.freepik.com/search?dates=any&format=search&page=1&query=Polygonal%20Human&sort=popular")
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.pagination__input.hide-phone>input[name='page']"))).get_attribute("max"))
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**snapshpt**:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Kunduk. However I got an error of 'selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: '. Please refer to my edited thread together with the new attached figure.

Comment: @balandongiv : Try now?? change it `presence_of_element_located()`

Comment: To follow up, does it necessary to include [name='page']? I thought this is part of the properties under the class pagination__input.hide-phone

Comment: @balandongiv : no you need to identify the input element which is under this `pagination__input.hide-phone`  tag and you need to make this unique so used most of the attribute to make it unique.Thanks.

Comment: @balandongiv : if tomorrow any new class added `div.pagination__input` and input tag then you won't get the max value.that is why always used most of the possible attribute.

Comment: In this case, whose approach is more robust to any possible changes by the webmaster? your or @frianH?

Comment: I didn’t say changes of any existing element.what I said if developer add any new element div.pagination__input on the webpage then you won’t get the max value.in your case when added it extra class then there must be some reason right.Hope you understood.